# Implement ToneJS Player with Reverb Effect

Tags: javascript, tonejs

Surely a silly question but I don't know how to implement my player with the reverb effect.

I've already try this :

```
playTone(){
    const player = new Tone.Player(this.songUrl);
    var decay = this.reverb / 100;
    const reverb = new Tone.Reverb(decay).toDestination();
    player.connect(reverb);
    Tone.loaded().then(() => {
      player.start();
    });
 }
```

But it's thrown me this error :

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidAccessError: The given
> destination is not connected

It works perfectly without the reverb effect, so maybe I missed something ...

Please help me, I'm searching since 2 hours ....